# GLSL/HLSL - Multiple single line conditional statements as opposed to single block

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu, hlsl, boolean-logic

Doing some research into antialiasing methods, I stumbled upon this piece of code (grabbed from Nvidia's FXAA shader):

```
if(!pairN) lumaN = lumaS;
if(!pairN) gradientN = gradientS;
if(!pairN) lengthSign *= -1.0;
```

Is there a good reason it's not written as the following instead?

```
if (!pairN) {
    lumaN = lumaS;
    gradientN = gradientS;
    lengthSign *= -1.0;
}
```

I assume it's an optimization of some sort? Just seems really counterintuitive...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is trivial for a GLSL compiler to convert this code:

```
if(!pairN) lumaN = lumaS;
if(!pairN) gradientN = gradientS;
if(!pairN) lengthSign *= -1.0;
```

into this branchless code:

```
lumaN = pair ? lumaN : lumaS;
gradientN = pair ? gradientN : gradientS;
lengthSign *= pair ? 1.0 : -1.0;
```

It is branchless in the sense it can be expressed as:

```
float a = float( pair );
float b = 1.0 - a;
lumaN = a * lumaN + b * lumaS;
gradientN = a * gradientN + b * gradientS;
lengthSign *= a * 1.0 + b * -1.0;
```

This is somewhat efficient optimization on mobile GPUs.

Automatically optimizing an entire `if` block is not so trivial.

Comment: Would modern GPU compilers not optimize the intuitive version then?

Comment: It looks like they are unable to optimize a large ``if`` block.

Comment: @skiwi If it's one thing I've learned about GLSL implementations over the years... the compiler does a lot of unexpected stuff. Some optimizations blow my mind and others I can hardly believe were missed. Trying both ways and looking at the intermediate output via `glGetProgramBinary` is as good as you can get.